# Convert String to Datetime (USING SSIS)

Tags: ssis

I want to insert a value "5/27/2013 16:42:37.490000" (Read from a flat file (DT_STR)) into a column(datetime) of SQL Server table . If I try to cast it with (DT_DBDATE) or DT_DBTIMESTAMP in a derived column , it gives an error .

```
[Derived Column [130]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "component "Derived Column" (130)" failed because error code 0xC0049064 occurred, and the error row disposition on "output column "Derived Column 1" (155)" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
```

How can I go about it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The value is a `datetime2` type .AFAIK SSIS doesn't support datetime2 .You need to store it in database as string and then update the column by converting it to datetime2.

Here is [Microsoft Connect Issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/731333/datetime2-format-not-supported-in-ssis-variables)

Update: Using `DT_DBTIMESTAMP2` you can convert the string to proper datetime format

The below code works perfectly fine in Derived Column

```
(DT_DBTIMESTAMP2,7)"2013-5-27 16:42:37.490000"
```

7 is the precession here .The above code won't work if the format of datetime is different.For example  `MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss.ffffff` .

However you can use `Script component` and pass array of different datetime formats to `Datetime.ParseExact` function

Step1: Drag a Script component and create a new output column of `DT_DBTIMESTAMP` datatype and name it as `NewDate`.

Step2: Write the below C# code

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
 {
  string[] format = new string[] { @"M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ffffff",
                                         @"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                                         @"M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss" ,
                                         @"M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ffffff",
                                         @"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ffffff",
                                          @"M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss.ffffff"};
  DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(Row.Date,
                format ,
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                DateTimeStyles.None);

  Row.newDate = dt;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Praveen for bringing it to my knowledge. What can be the work around for this ? Conversion, as you mentioned above can't be applied to due certain constraints.

Comment: @Akshay No, an entry at that MS Connect link says:  "To use a DATETIME2 type in SSIS, use the DT_DBTIMESTAMP2 type."  It was an AS400 DATETIME2 type that wasn't supported.  For the SQL Server type, you just need to know to call it "DT_DBTIMESTAMP2".

Comment: I am not able to use that and hence the question. Could you please tell the expression that I could use. Right now the SQL table column is of (DATETIME Type). How can i insert the value mentioned above ? Do i need to alter my table column type ???

Comment: Insert into a dummy table first as a varchar and convert that column back to datetime2 using execute sql task.

Answer (score 1):

I won't say it's the perfect solution, but just a workaround. 
Format the input and then insert. The formatted data after using the below expression works well with either datetime or datetime2.

```
SUBSTRING(TMS_CREAT,(FINDSTRING(TMS_CREAT,"/",2) + 1),4) + "-" + SUBSTRING(TMS_CREAT,1,(FINDSTRING(TMS_CREAT,"/",1) - 1)) + "-" + SUBSTRING(TMS_CREAT,(FINDSTRING(TMS_CREAT,"/",1) + 1),2) + SUBSTRING(TMS_CREAT,(FINDSTRING(TMS_CREAT,"/",2) + 5),16)
```

Comment: This is not an efficient way of doing it .Moreover it will fail if you have date in the format Example `5/7/2013 16:42:27.490000`

Comment: You are right. It was never meant for PROD type of work . It won't fail if I add some more constraints in it but yes your solution is no doubt better.