# date type from Oracle to SQL with SSIS Problems

Tags: oracle, ssis

I've been trying to extract some information from Oracle to a table in SQL server using SSIS but I am having the next message error:

I've been trying to extract some information from Oracle to a table in SQL server using SSIS but I am having the next message error.

**Data conversion failed while converting column "DATE_OFFICE" (294) to column "Copy of DATE_OFFICE" (96).**

I decided to export the table from Oracle to a Excel file and emulate the extraction process from there, and I did not have any problem. Also, I looked for some possible strange data in the column of the date type but I found nothing wrong, the format of these dates was "dd-mmm-yy", and in the sql server the table loaded this data with this format: "yyyy-mm-dd", and there were any kind of problem.

So, what can I do in the conversion type task to avoid or fix this error?, is it good to try to choose another kind of date format as an output?

I decided to export the table from Oracle to a Excel file and emulate the extraction process from there, and I did not have any problem. Also, I looked for some possible strange data in the column of the date type but I found nothing wrong, the format of these dates was "dd-mmm-yy", and in the sql server the table loaded this data with this format: "yyyy-mm-dd", and there were any kind of problem.

So, what can I do in the conversion type task to avoid or fix this error?, is it good to try to choose another kind of date format as an output?

[image]

The data type coming from Oracle is interpreted as DT_DBTIMESTAMP and I am attempting to convert it to DT_DATE.

Comment: What are the values being sent from Oracle? If you double click the connector between Source and Data Conversion and chose the Metatdata, what is the metadata for the DATE_OFFICE column? What data type are you attempting to convert it to

Answer (score 1):

Basing on your comment, can you switch the destination type to `DT_DBTIMESTAMP2`
DT_DBTIMESTAMP2 is the new data type that is supported in SQL 2008 and above for timestamps in this format '2015-01-14 13:45:41.417'

[Look at this related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813903/convert-string-to-datetime-using-ssis)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type

Comment: take a peek [at this issue](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic551496-148-1.aspx).