# How to convert 14-DEC-16 06.23.37.000 to datetime in ssis

Tags: ssis

I have 14-DEC-16 06.23.37.000 date in csv file.

How to convert 14-DEC-16 06.23.37.000 to datetime in ssis and insert in to sql table.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: Either use a Derived Column or a Script transformation. This format is so unusual that there's no chance you can find a ready-made conversion, especially when you talk about dates in **1916**. I suggest you fix the source or the export process to use four-digit years. Better yet change it to export in the ISO8601 format

Comment: Using two-digit years means you have no idea what you are importing. We've already gone through the trouble this caused with Y2K. Reintroducint such a well known bug is inexcusable. There is also no reason to assume that `14-DEC-16` is 2016 instead of 1916. That's the second year of WWI. There are commemorative events **NOW** about events back then. You'll find plenty of similar dates for the next 2-3 years.

Comment: Could you please explain logic for this in script as this is the requirment

Comment: @user7434607 just google for this. You'll find a lot of information both for Derived Column formulas and DateTime parsing for script tasks. The real solution is to fix the broken export format. There are also a lot of duplicate questions about both.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert String to Datetime (USING SSIS)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813903/convert-string-to-datetime-using-ssis)

Comment: Where does the data come from and why are dates in this format? What tool is used to produce this? All export tools allow you to specify the format. It would be a lot easier to change the appropriate flag in the tool's format file or command line.

Comment: Data is in csv file and need to insert in sql table using ssis

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly you are working on data where you KNOW that there will be no dates outside of the bounds 2000 - 2099 and you KNOW that you will always get the same string format with ENG month abbreviations in it, you can use the following conversion:

```
DECLARE @DateString nvarchar(50) = N'14-DEC-16 06.23.37.000';

WITH cte AS(
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN CHARINDEX('-DEC-', @DateString) > 0 THEN REPLACE(@DateString, '-DEC-', '.12.20')
    WHEN CHARINDEX('-NOV-', @DateString) > 0 THEN REPLACE(@DateString, '-NOV-', '.11.20')
    WHEN CHARINDEX('-OCT-', @DateString) > 0 THEN REPLACE(@DateString, '-OCT-', '.10.20')
    WHEN CHARINDEX('-SEP-', @DateString) > 0 THEN REPLACE(@DateString, '-SEP-', '.09.20')
    WHEN CHARINDEX('-AUG-', @DateString) > 0 THEN REPLACE(@DateString, '-AUG-', '.08.20')
    WHEN CHARINDEX('-JUL-', @DateString) > 0 THEN REPLACE(@DateString, '-JUL-', '.07.20')
    WHEN CHARINDEX('-JUN-', @DateString) > 0 THEN REPLACE(@DateString, '-JUN-', '.06.20')
    WHEN CHARINDEX('-MAY-', @DateString) > 0 THEN REPLACE(@DateString, '-MAY-', '.05.20')
    WHEN CHARINDEX('-APR-', @DateString) > 0 THEN REPLACE(@DateString, '-APR-', '.04.20')
    WHEN CHARINDEX('-MAR-', @DateString) > 0 THEN REPLACE(@DateString, '-MAR-', '.03.20')
    WHEN CHARINDEX('-FEB-', @DateString) > 0 THEN REPLACE(@DateString, '-FEB-', '.02.20')
    WHEN CHARINDEX('-JAN-', @DateString) > 0 THEN REPLACE(@DateString, '-JAN-', '.01.20')
  END AS DateString
)
SELECT DateString,
       CONVERT(datetime, RIGHT(LEFT(DateString, 10),4)+'-'+SUBSTRING(LEFT(DateString, 10),4,2)+'-'+LEFT(LEFT(DateString, 10),2) +
                         REPLACE(LEFT(RIGHT(DateString,13),9),'.',':') + RIGHT(DateString, 4)) AS MyDate
  FROM cte
```

I defined @DateString, but here you can use the column alias as well.

Comment: How to use this in ssis

Comment: One quite quick&dirty approach might be to simply execute it as "Execute SQL task" and fetch the Result into a variable. Another possibility would be to create a derived column and use the SSIS specific string handling within an expression on this column.